# Funciones en espacios de nombres anónimos, separar declaración/definición

Tags: c++

Dispongo de una cabecera que declara una función en un espacio de nombres llamado `test` y anidado en este espacio de nombres se en encuentra un espacio de nombres anónimo que declara otra función:

`test.hpp`

```
namespace test
{
namespace
{

void test(); // void test::<anónimo>::test();

}

void f(); // void test::f();

}
```

Si se incluye la cabecera `test.hpp` se tendrá acceso a `void test::f()` pero no se podrá tener acceso a `void test::<anónimo>::test();`. El archivo de código tiene el siguiente aspecto:

`test.cpp`

```
namespace test
{
namespace
{

void test()
{
    std::cout << 42u << '\n';
}

}

void f()
{
    test();
}

}
```

La función del espacio de nombres `test` llama internamente a la función del espacio de nombres anónimo anidado, con esta configuración el código mostrado a continuación falla o ejecuta según el compilador:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    /* clang 10.0.0 -> Compila con alarmas.
           warning: unused function 'test'
    */
    /* gcc 10.0.0.20190 -> No compila, mismas alarmas.
           warning: 'void test::{anonymous}::test()' declared 'static' but never defined
           undefined reference to `test::f()'
    */
    test::f();
    return 0;
}
```

En <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A9UbsxJ7aE2G1Kpk)</kbd> hay una versión del código para hacer pruebas.

¿Qué compilador está en lo cierto? ¿Se pueden definir por separado funciones declaradas en un espacio de nombres anónimo o deben ser definidas-declaradas en el mismo punto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Se pueden definir por separado funciones declaradas en un espacio de nombres anónimo o deben ser definidas-declaradas en el mismo punto?

Realmente no estás separando la declaración de la implementación.

El espacio de nombres anónimo de la cabecera viaja a cada unidad de compilación, luego la declaración de la función estará presente en varias unidades de compilación.

La implementación de la función, en cambio, existe solamente en la unidad de compilación de `test.cpp`.

Así pues las advertencias que comentas te saldrán por cada unidad de compilación que incluya `test.h`, ya que en todas estas unidades **no existirá la implementación de la función**.

Es facil demostrar este punto, basta con declarar una implementación personalizada en `main.cpp` para ver como todo compila perfectamente y sin errores:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

namespace test
{
  namespace
  {
    void test()
    { std::cout << "kaka\n"; }
  }
}

int main()
{
    test::test();
    test::f();
    return 0;
}
```

Con este cambio, el programa devolverá la siguiente salida:

```
kaka
XXX
```

Quedando claro que cada unidad de compilación genera su propio espacio de nombres anónimo, de tal forma que ambas implementaciones de `test()` no colisionan entre sí.

Este efecto se puede conseguir también eliminando el espacio de nombres anónimo de `test.h`, con lo que queda demostrado que dicha declaración **no sirve absolutamente para nada**, siendo algo totalmente accesorio que únicamente sirve para generar warnings totalmente innecesarios.

> ¿Qué compilador está en lo cierto?

Dado que no es necesario implementar una función que no se va a usar, yo me inclinaría más por el comportamiento de CLang.

Aun así yo intentaría no generar este paquete de advertencias. No le veo utilidad práctica alguna.

Si se desea, por la razón que sea, separar la declaración y la implementación de una función en un espacio de nombres anónimo se puede optar por declarar e implementar todo en el `cpp`:

```
namespace
{
  void test();
}

// ...

namespace
{
  test()
  { std::cout << "YYYY"; }
}
```

Pero a mi modo de ver esta práctica solo serviría para que el código fuente fuese más verboso y complejo de leer.

Bueno, ya puestos a ser perversos con el código también podríamos aislar la declaración y la implementación en sendos archivos (cabecera e implementación) y hacer los `includes` dentro del espacio de nombres anónimo... que cada uno saque sus propias conclusiones sobre la utilidad de estas prácticas...

`anon.h`

```
// No hacen falta guardas porque no es un include normal

void test();
```

`anon.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
std::cout << "YYYY";
}
```

`test.h`

```
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST

namespace test
{
  void f();
}

#endif
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"

namespace test
{
  namespace
  {
    #include "anon.h"
  }

  void f()
  {
    test();
  }

  namespace
  {
    #include "anon.cpp"
  }
}
```